# datetime strptime returning wrong pattern

Tags: perl

I pull a date from a file and I'm creating a datetime object by using this command and then adding 1 to it to get the next date.

```
my $parseit = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%Y%m%d');
my $lastdate = "20190115";
my $tempdate = $parseit->parse_datetime($lastdate);
my $date_up1 = $tempdate->add(days => 1);
```

but in printing out the variable $date_up1 I always get it in the form %Y-%m-%d.  How can I just get it returned in the pattern that I selected.

Comment: `my $date_up1 = $tempdate->add(days => 1);` is the same as `$tempdate->add(days => 1); my $date_up1 = $tempdate;`, so it's a bit weird

Comment: Perhaps the OP didn't know that DateTime math mutates the object; to get non-mutable behavior (which tends to be preferred in more complex operations, and is done excellently by [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment)) you must `->clone` the object before any math operation or `->set`.

Comment: @Grinnz, Re "*Perhaps the OP didn't know that DateTime math mutates the object*", Which is why I told them... /// Re "*[A non-mutable object] tends to be preferred in more complex operations*", Quite the opposite. Non-mutable objects are more expensive and more complex. As such, they are only used for simple values.

Comment: @ikegami It's of course an opinionated discussion that probably does not belong here, but (unknown to the user) mutable objects [have been known to lead to serious bugs](https://rjbs.manxome.org/rubric/entry/1929). [another point of view](https://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/do-you-copy/)

Comment: Time::Moment's API as I mentioned is a great example of how a non-mutable API can be predictable and straightforward, IMO. You are correct that it is by necessity more expensive; though Time::Moment is much simpler and more efficient than DateTime to begin with, due to not having any time-zone or locale features beyond localtime.

Comment: @Grinnz, I definitely agree that mutable objects are more error-prone to use. All I said it's that hey're just harder to get right for more complex values, and definitely far more expensive. Date-time values are actually quite simple (they can possibly  be reduced to an epoch ts plus tz info), so a immutable dt class would be possible without much difficulty

Answer (score 2):

strptime and thus DateTime::Format::Strptime by default only dictates how you parse the input into a DateTime object. DateTime objects default to a specific stringification, which you are seeing. In order to stringify it in a certain way, you can use its [strftime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Estrftime(-$format,-...-)) method.

```
print $date_up1->strftime('%Y%m%d');
```

Comment: @ikegami I've edited the answer, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

While DateTime::Format::Strptime can be used to both parse and format date times, it doesn't set itself as the default formatter for the DateTime objects it creates as you expect. You can do that explicitly by adding the following:

```
$tempdate->set_formatter($parseit);
```

After cleaning up your code, it looks like this:

```
my $date = "20190115";

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern  => '%Y%m%d',
   on_error => 'croak',
);

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($date);
$dt->set_formatter($format);
$dt->add( days => 1 );
say $dt;
```

Alternatively, all of the following work without setting the formatter:

- `$format->format_datetime($dt)`
- `$dt->strftime("%Y%m%d")` (Most flexible, but introduces duplicate code in this case)
- `$dt->ymd("")` (Simplest in this case)